# Callable to add to list_display that references extra field in the intermediary model of a M2M relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models, `Tender` and `Status`, that have a many-to-many relationship with an intermediary model `TenderStatus`. `TenderStatus` has an extra date field which denotes the date on which each status was applied. I want to show all the statuses for each Tender in the list_display. I understand that I have to create a callable in my `TenderAdmin` class to include in list_display, and although I am able to list out the statuses, I'm having trouble accessing the date field in the intermediary model.

Here's an abbreviated version of my models.py:

```py
class Tender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=False
    )
    tender_status = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Status',
        through='TenderStatus',
        related_name='tender_status'
    )

class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        null=False
    )

class TenderStatus(models.Model):
    tender = models.ForeignKey('Tender', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=False)
    status = models.ForeignKey('Status', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=False)
```

And here's an abbreviated admin.py--note the `status_list` callable, this one works but it doesn't have the date in there. Any attempts I've made to access the date have not worked.

```py
class TenderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
    list_display = ['name', 'status_list']

    def status_list(self, obj):
        return [x.status for x in obj.tender_status.all()]
    status_list.allow_tags = True
```

I've tried this, but it can't find the date and returns a 500 error:

```py
    def status_list(self, obj):
        return [str(x.date) + ': ' + x.status for x in obj.tender_status.all()]
```

Any help finding the right way to write that status_list function so it accesses the date would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, I figured out the answer. Extra fields on many-to-many relationships [are covered in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/), but not particularly thoroughly and the example they give would only work for a single returned object (which--why would you even use a M2M for that? Anyway). The gist is that you have to directly query the intermediary model, passing the `obj` as a parameter on a filter. Here's the callable I created that works:

```py
    def status_list(self, obj):
        statuses = TenderStatus.objects.filter(tender=obj)
        return ', '.join([str(x.date) + ': ' + str(x.status) for x in statuses.all()])
```

Hope that helps someone else!